How to Wait for Pinia Store Data Initialization Before Assigning Variables in Vue3 Component?
I'm building a Vue.js application using Pinia for state management. In my component, I need to assign variables based on data retrieved from a Pinia store. However, I'm encountering an issue where the component assigns variables before the store data is initialized, leading to undefined errors. Using the browser extention, I can view my store, which is populated with the 5 objects pulled from the json file. In the console I am getting: task.value is undefined.
I have tried a few recommendations from ChatGPT such as using watch or watchEffect but until now nothing has worked.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
// Pinia storesetup
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useTaskStore = defineStore('tasks', () => {
  const tasks = ref([])

  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/src/data.json')
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
      }
      const data = await response.json()
      tasks.value = data.tasks
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching tasks:', error)
    }
  }

  const getTaskById = computed(() => {
    return (taskId) => tasks.value.find((task) => task.id === taskId)
  })

  function addTask(task) {
    tasks.value.push(task)
  }

  function deleteTask(task) {
    const index = tasks.value.findIndex((t) => t.id === task.id)
    if (index !== -1) {
      tasks.value.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }

  fetchData()

  return {
    addTask,
    deleteTask,
    getTaskById,
    tasks
  }
})

And here is my component (simplified as the template isn't important):
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, watchEffect, computed } from 'vue'
import { useTaskStore } from '@/stores/TaskStore'
const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})
const store = useTaskStore()

const task = computed(() => store.getTaskById(props.id))

let titleEditing = ref(false)
let descriptionEditing = ref(false)
const editedTitle = ref(task.value.title)

I have tried using onMounted, beforeMounted, watchEffect and watch. I have tried declaring a const with a ref to an empty object, and used watchEffect/watch to update the object when the state changes.
I expected beforeMounted to work because, the store would be initilizes and filled with data before the component is mounted and the variables are filled with data from the store, but wasn't the case.
Attempt using watch:
watch(
  () => store.tasks,
  (newTasks, oldTasks) => {
    if (newTasks !== oldTasks) {
      task.value = store.getTaskById(props.id)
    }
  }
)


Could be from the fact that the task data is being fetched asynchronously and this takes a certain amount of time to complete.  The task computed property is undefined while the fetch is ongoing.  You need to handle this case.  Either editedTitle should be another computed property or you can use a watch to assign the title value once task has a value

You should indeed have an undefined state until the whole async call comes back to you. Once it is retrieved you should have your state update. watch is indeed a way to live your life. What have you tried with it exactly? Mount and beforeMount will be resolved before the call is.

Also consider ditching AI in favor of reading the official documentation. You gonna waste less time and have better results long run.

So I have tried using watch like this, but even when the state has updated(The data was fetched), nothing is rendering because I assume the values which are relying on task already try to initialize and fail...
`const task = ref(null)
watch(
() => store.tasks,
(newTasks, oldTasks) => {
if (newTasks !== oldTasks) {
task.value = store.getTaskById(props.id)
}
}
)`

It is reactive so it will be updated if one of it's reactive dependencies are updated. Where do you call the function to fetch the data? What values are inside of the new tasks in the watch?

@kissu
I am calling fetchData() directly in the store, so that when the store is initialised, it populated the tasks array with the data from the JSON. The values of new tasks in the watch function are my 5 task objects from the store.tasks... I think I might have to sleep on this, as my brain is fried trying to figure out how to get this to work

@sasky71 "I am calling fetchData() directly in the store" - this is the problem here, you lose the ability to chain a promise by doing this in a scope that cannot be accessed somewhere else. This needs to be done in some component higher than ones where you consume this data and the children shouldn't be rendered until the promise is resolved

I have faced something similar in a project I´m working on. At first, I solved it by using watch() to check if it was loaded for the first time, and also watchEffect() if it was already loaded and something has changed inside of it.
After some time, I found a better way to do it, which was as obvious as it could be
The problem was: "The variables failed to receive a value because the promises were not resolving in time"
The solution: "Let's make the program wait"
Heres is my pinia fetchData code:
async fetchData() {
  if (!this.dataLoaded && this.agentsTable.length == 0) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/agents`);
      response.data.forEach(agent => {
        this.agentsTable.push(agent);
      });
      this.dataLoaded = true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in request api agents', error);
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401 || error.code == 'ERR_NETWORK' || error.code =='ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED') {
        this.logout();
      }
    }
  }
},

And here is how I'm managing it in my template script:
import { useCachedDataStoreAgents } from '../../stores/agentsStore';
 async function fetchData() {
       await useCachedDataStoreAgents().fetchData();
       loadingFlag.value = false;
 }
 fetchData();

Calling the fetchData() method on the imported element of the pinia store, and making the script await for it before further execution, ensures that the variables receive their assigned values in time
Hope this experience helps you
